# Is there a way to get the result of a BulkInsert with ravendb

Tags: c#, ravendb, bulkinsert

I have a bulkInsert operation in the system i'm working on and i need to get the result of what has been done by the bulkInsert. 
More precisly i need the id of all the document added in the operation.

The changeApi doesn't give me this information, only when the bulk begin and end.
But i have the operationId and in the doc 
https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/csharp/glossary/operation their seems to be a way to RetrieveDetails on each document affected.
https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/csharp/glossary/bulk-operation-options

I can't figure out how to do this or if it is even possible.

Answer (score 0):

This information is not exposed, bulk insert is meant for very large number of documents, so we don't keep track of this information.
You need to maintain that yourself.